# Logitech S-150 Speakers wont work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb, sound, logitech

I recently bought a pair of logitech's S-150 speakers to use with my new ubuntu setup. In the sound control pannel, I have "digital output (S/PDIF) | USB AUDIO" and "Analog Output | USB AUDIO". When I try to test either of these, nothing comes out of the speakers. The speakers work on my windows computer, and control the volume of the Ubuntu computer when the volume buttons on the speakers are pressed.

I am at a loss of what to try next. When googling for the problem, I come up with many results from 5-6 years ago, with terminal commands that are obsolete.

Comment: The sound works in Xubuntu 18.04 (upgrading, if you haven't already, may fix the problem). It should be noted that the buttons don't work for me in 18.04, however.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem: could not get sound out of Logitech S-150. When I went into Sound Settings and changed it to USB and closed out, it would still be on HDMI when I went back in. It should stay on whatever is highlighted when you close the window.

I ran `pulseaudio -k` in terminal and that fixed my issue. Now when I choose USB in Sound Settings and move the volume bar up I hear sound out of the Logitech S150 and also I can now change it to another output and close out of Sound Settings and it stays on what I had picked.

If that does not work, you might want to also install/run pavucontrol and see if the USB AUDIO is an option on the Output Devices tab. You will want to resize the window so you see all of the tabs at the top. If you see the USB AUDIO on the Output Devices tab but sound is not coming out of them then play some music and go to the Playback tab and click on HDMI or whatever shows and pick USB AUDIO from the list. Make sure your volume is on the low side so you don't max the speakers out when the sound finally does come through.

Comment: Yup, `pulseaudio -k` is all it takes. Other solutions I've seen involve modifying system configurations, and other hacky methods. Thank God I found this before trying any of the other ones