# How to get buttons on my Logitech S-150 speakers to function on Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, usb, xubuntu, speakers, logitech

So, I just got some [Logitech S-150 USB digital speakers](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Logitech-S150-2-0-USB-Digital-Speakers-Black/11017024) for $7.46 at Walmart.com on January 4th (they've updated the price since). I'm using them on Xubuntu 18.04, 64-bit. The sound works fine (no problems there). However, the three buttons on the speaker seem to do absolutely nothing. Is there a way to get my computer to recognize those?

In this previous question, someone had the inverse problem (the sound wouldn't work, but the buttons did): [Logitech S-150 Speakers wont work on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783226/logitech-s-150-speakers-wont-work-on-ubuntu-16-04)

So, it looks like it's possible to get the buttons working.

At the end of the day, the issue doesn't really bother me (the speakers work and I can control the volume via my computer; with the volume all the way up, it's already pretty loud), but I thought I'd ask, since I'm curious.

The Logitech website doesn't seem to have any drivers.